# Couldn't match expected type ‘(Int, Int)’ with actual type ‘[t0]’

Tags: haskell

why is this giving me error? I am just trying this as a test to learn Haskell where i am just strapping off the tuples in the second input. Why does this not compile ? Thank you

```
test :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int
test [] [] = []
test xs [] = []
test (x,xs) (y:ys)  =   test (x,xs) ys
```

Thank you @Carcigenicate for pointing out the first error. Now if we have

```
test :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int
test xs [] = []
test (x,xs) (y:ys)  =   test (x,xs) ys
```

I get

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[t0]’
• In the expression: []
  In an equation for ‘test’: test xs [] = []
```

Comment: Looks like because you said the first argument is a 2-tuple, then you tried to pattern match it with a list in the first definition. Tuples can't be empty iirc.

Comment: The `test` function's first argument is a tuple and second is a list of tuples but your pattern matching is not correct.

Comment: You say that the function returns an int, then you try to return a [] on that line, which isn't an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function signature says that the first argument should be a tuple of 2 ints, but then in your first pattern matching line:

```
test [] [] = []
      ^
```

You try to match a tuple against a list.

1. The types don't match, thus the error.
2. A tuple will never be empty unless that's what type it is. Unlike lists, tuples can't be added to or removed from; they have a fixed size.

If you said the tuple will have 2 values, it will always have 2 values. No need to check if it's empty. It looks like you can get rid of that line, since it's not doing anything legal or useful.

Also note your naming is a little confusing. Typically, `x` and `xs` represent the head and tail of a collection. Tuples don't really have either, just different "slots".

Comment: Hey thanks, i removed it and i get this  "Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[t0]’"

Comment: i will add it as a modification

Comment: @ElBazzi And why do you even have the first argument? It's not doing anything.

Comment: @ElBazzi Note the comment I added to the question. Really, each question should be a single question. If this answer solved your original question, mark it as solved by hitting the check mark, and upvote my answer if it helped you. If you need further help, you can open a new question, or contact me at the email address in my profile. I'd encourage you to really read over the error messages though, as they're quite informative.

Comment: @ElBazzi No problem.